How exactly does RF to IF conversion work in an AM radio?
I am currently researching AM radio detection circuits. From my understanding, RF is received, amplified and converted to an IF(455khz for AM) before being converted into an audible frequency for amplification.
IF to AF is understandable, a simple diode-detector circuit doing the conversion with a capacitor that holds the previous analog value whenever the carrier dips.
However, how is AM RF converted into a lower IF?


how is AM RF converted into a lower IF?

It is called "superhetherodyne" conversion.

For details, it is all explained in Wikipedia.


However, how is AM RF converted into a lower IF?

The heterodyne principle can be used with a diode in this simplified mixer, reduced to its bare bones:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
 V1 would be the small-signal AM radio input.
V2 is a large amplitude sine wave "local oscillator". The two signals are added and presented to a non-linear element - in this case a diode.
V(out) consists of many frequency components as well as V1 and V2. Of particular interest is the mixing component of frequency 1.455MHz minus 1.000 MHz. This component contains all the amplitude-modulated information of V1.
The intermediate-frequency amplifier at 455 kHz passes V(out) while rejecting all other frequency components. The selectivity is omitted from this simple picture above.

Can it be explained in the manner of OP's diode detector?...
At the moment when large-amplitude V2 reaches its positive peak, diode D1 is strongly conducting. Along with it rides the signal of interest (V1) to R1.
At the moment when large-amplitude V2 reaches its negative peak, diode D1 is open-circuit, and V1 is prevented from reaching R1, whose voltage is zero.
D1 acts as a switch, turning on, then off 1455000 times each second.

The key to this type of RF frequency conversion is the mixer as is shown in the diagrams by Ale..chenski and the diode (which is functioning as a mixer) in glen_geek's diagram.
Unlike most elements in a RF chain such as amplifiers and filters, a mixer is a non-liner device.
In a device operating in the linear mode, if two frequencies f1 and f2 are input to that device the output is those same two frequencies, both amplified (in the case of an amplifier).
In a device operating in a non-linear mode, the output would be frequencies f1 and f2 but also f1-f2 and f1+f2, and perhaps other frequencies.  The designer chooses which output frequency to further process by using a filter that only passes the desired frequency.
So let's say you have an input frequency of 1.6 MHz (the high end of the AM band) , and an IF frequency of 455 KHz.  You mix the 1.6 MHz input with a 2.055 MHz local oscillator (LO) frequency.  The output of the mixer is the sum 3.655 MHz and the difference, 455 KHz.  The 3.655 MHz component is rejected by the filters that follow the mixer.
Just as an aside, designing good mixers is not a easy task and engineers can spends years becoming experts in this field.
